# Difficulty pinpointing issue on PC that won't boot

Tags: windows-xp, hard-drive, boot

I have been trying to troubleshoot an old PC that is being used in a monitoring system at work. Twice now I have been able to start up into Windows but the computer will reboot before it has fully started up (while some of the monitoring applications are initializing). When looking through the BIOS the HDD isn't even listed in the boot sequence at all and when booting off the windows xp install cd into "Windows Setup" there is no HDD listed to repair. Also, I hear a constant quiet beeping (every 0.5 seconds) from the moment the computer is booted up to the moment it shuts down.

Is it possible that this is anything other than a failed HDD? We are considering sending the unit back to the manufacturer but it is no longer under warranty and the wait time could be significant. If this is something I can fix myself it would be VERY preferable.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There are a lot of possible parts that are broken. Isolate them (remove from the system, one at a time, to see if you still have the same symptoms):

- Hard Drive
- CD Drive
- RAM (Leave one stick in, test, then swap the stick with another one if you have two)
- Power supply (test with another power supply from a working computer, or a power supply tester / multimeter)

If the beeping is coming from the onboard speaker (not a hard drive seek sound, which sounds like a beep but is mechanical), I'd test the power supply. Remove the power and data connections to the hard drive and CD drive, boot it, and see if you hear the beeping still.

If you don't hear the beeping, plug the hard drive into another computer - Boot into your usual OS for the computer, then just see if you can see the C drive from the other computer (usually will be called E:). If you can see if, the hard drive is probably good and the other computer is probably bad. If you can't see it, the drive may be going bad. Recovery will cost around $2,000 USD if you absolutely need the data from it. If you hear the same beeping noise on this system, copy any important data off it immediately - The drive is going bad.

Best advice: If you aren't comfortable with this, hire someone to take a look. In the US, try [Craigslist](http://www.craigslist.org) or [OnForce](http://www.onforce.com). Don't go for cheap - Get some that charges at least $70/hr (if in the US in a major metro area, else middle of the road), and has references, especially on Craigslist. Don't send the PC to the manufacturer - It's cheaper to buy a new PC and make it work for your application, or have someone local fix it.